# Why the scrollbar doesn't appear this extjs code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs, extjs4

I was testing accordian layout and ran into a problem, this is the code

```
var myData = [
    ['3m Co',                               71.72, 0.02,  0.03,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Alcoa Inc',                           29.01, 0.42,  1.47,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Altria Group Inc',                    83.81, 0.28,  0.34,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['American Express Company',            52.55, 0.01,  0.02,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['American International Group, Inc.',  64.13, 0.31,  0.49,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['AT&T Inc.',                           31.61, -0.48, -1.54, '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Boeing Co.',                          75.43, 0.53,  0.71,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Caterpillar Inc.',                    67.27, 0.92,  1.39,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Citigroup, Inc.',                     49.37, 0.02,  0.04,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['E.I. du Pont de Nemours and Company', 40.48, 0.51,  1.28,  '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['Exxon Mobil Corp',                    68.1,  -0.43, -0.64, '9/1 12:00am'],
    ['General Electric Company',            34.14, -0.08, -0.23, '9/1 12:00am']
];

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
    fields: [
       {name: 'company'},
       {name: 'price',      type: 'float'},
       {name: 'change',     type: 'float'},
       {name: 'pctChange',  type: 'float'},
       {name: 'lastChange', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'n/j h:ia'}
    ],
    data: myData
});


Ext.create('widget.window', {
      title: 'Activity',
      closable: true,
      closeAction: 'hide',
      width: 250,
      height: 300,
      bodyBorder: true,
      tbar: {
          xtype: 'toolbar',
          ui: 'plain',
          items: [{
              iconCls:'refresh'
          },
          '->',
          {
              xtype: 'displayfield',
              name: 'act_date',
              id: 'act_date',
              value: '2011-08-08'
          }]
      },      
      layout:'accordion',
      border: false,
      items: [{
                title: 'Recent activity',
                items: [{
                            xtype: 'grid',
                            store: store,
                            hideHeaders: true,
                            border: 0,
                            autoScroll: true,
                            columns: [{
                                        text     : 'Company',
                                        flex     : 1,
                                        sortable : false,
                                        dataIndex: 'company'
                                    },{
                                        text     : 'Price',
                                        width    : 75,
                                        sortable : true,
                                        renderer : 'usMoney',
                                        dataIndex: 'price'
                                    }]

                        }]
            },{
                title: 'Recent activity',
                html: ''
            },{
                title: 'Recent activity',
                html: ''
            }]  

}).show();
```

output is like

[image]

the scroll bar doesn't appear in the grid. any idea why it doesn't?

Regards

solution1 = Kiran's answer
solution2 = http://jsfiddle.net/MmBWF/

Comment: I think you have to add `overflow: auto` beneath the `height: 300` in `Ext.create('widget.window', {` code.

Comment: This is actually a CSS property to give a scrollbar to fixed height div while the content is more.

Comment: tried that like style: {overflow:'auto'}, but doesn't work

Comment: have you applied it to the relevant div style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify height for the grid which you are trying to display the data.Then it will calculate the height, at the time of overflow it will display the scroll bar.

Check the below link:

http://jsfiddle.net/NswjV/

Comment: thanks. by setting size there is another problem which scroll bar goes underneath the accordian

Comment: i tried create grid outside the accordion and add it, then it works nicely  http://jsfiddle.net/bfaFS/    maybe its a bug in extjs?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you have an extra container within the accordion container containing your grid.

I removed this and you can see the result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NswjV/2/)